# 'data validation rule limit of 500' error on google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to implement the script to the spreadsheet which will get all folder list and all files list in subfolder of Google drive api with this code,

[I found on this [forum]](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/CqEKvGvOU8U/PkLRxw7h2XgJ)

```js
//GLOBAL VARIABLES

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheets()[0];
var listCell = 'B1';
var idRange = 'A2:B2';
var idCell = 'B2';

function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Get Files From Folder')
    .addItem('STEP 1: Get my folders', 'getAllFolders')
    .addItem('STEP 2: Get ID of selected folder', 'getId')
    .addItem('STEP 3: Get all Files', 'getAllFiles')
    .addToUi();
}

function getAllFolders() {
  var arr = [];
  var all = DriveApp.getFolders();
  while (all.hasNext()) {
    var folder = all.next();
    arr.push(folder.getName())
  }
  arr.sort(function(first, next) {
    first.toLowerCase(),
      next.toLowerCase();
    return first < next ? -1 : first > next ? 1 : 0;
  });
  var cell = ss.getRange(listCell);
  cell.setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
      .requireValueInList(arr, true)
      .build())
    .setVerticalAlignment('middle');
  cell.offset(0, -1)
    .setValue('FOLDERS: ')
    .setBackground('#50803c')
    .setFontColor('White')
    .setFontWeight('Bold')
    .setHorizontalAlignment('center')
    .setVerticalAlignment('middle');
  ss.setRowHeight(1, 50);
}
//STEP2

function getId() {
  ss.getRange(idRange)
    .setValues([
      ["ID: ", DriveApp.getFoldersByName(ss.getRange(listCell)
          .getValue())
        .next()
        .getId()
      ]
    ])
    .setVerticalAlignment('middle')
    .setFontColor('grey');
}


//STEP3

function getAllFiles() {
  var id = ss.getRange(idCell).getValue();
  ss.getRange(4, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).clear();
  var arr = [
    ["FILENAME", "URL"]
  ];
  var f = DriveApp.getFolderById(id).getFiles()
  while (f.hasNext()) {
    var file = f.next();
    var name = file.getName()
    arr.push([name, '=HYPERLINK("' + file
      .getUrl() + '"; "' + name + '")'
    ]);
  }
  ss.getRange(4, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
}
```

but I got an error

> The data validation rule has more items than the limit of 500. Use the "List from a range" criteria instead.

I have no clue why I got this error, probably too many subfolders

Is there anyway to edit code to get 3 level of subfolder like

root folder > subfolder1 >subfolder2>subfolder3

or anything that can solve this error ,Thanks

Comment: do I have no luck with this?? (T_T)

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue exactly as the error message says. You may check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). Apps Script services impose daily quotas and hard limitations on some features. If you exceed a quota or limitation, your script will throw an exception and terminate execution.

Comment: I can't find it in the documentation. Could you please show where it is?

Answer (score 1):

When you make data validation (DV) rule with a list as a source, and the number of items is > 500, you'll get the error.

I've got the same error and did not find any mention of this limit in Documentation.

See the only solution, If `arr.length > 500`:

1. Create helper sheet
2. Write the data from your list on the sheet
3. Make DV rule [with a range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInRange(Range)) as a source.

Note. The array `arr` is 1-dimensional array: `[val1, val2, ...]`. When you'll write the data to a range, first convert it into a column, 2D array: `[[val1], [val2], [...]]`